# What is the format to add a comment in a paket's file?

Tags: paket

My current pake.dependencies look like this:

```yaml
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
storage: none
framework: netstandard2.0
strategy: min
lowest_matching: true

nuget FSharp.Core >= 5.0.0
nuget TypeShape >= 10.0.0

group test
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
storage: none
framework: net6.0

nuget FsCheck
nuget FsCheck.Xunit
nuget Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
nuget xunit
nuget xunit.runner.visualstudio
```

I would like to comment one or more lines.

```yaml
storage: none
/* See the reason why `netstandard2.0` at shorturl.at/oKMU3 */
framework: netstandard2.0
strategy: min
lowest_matching: true
```

The code can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/d-edge/Diffract)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `//` or `#` to comment in a paket file:

```
storage: none
# See the reason why `netstandard2.0` at shorturl.at/oKMU3
framework: netstandard2.0
strategy: min
lowest_matching: true
```

Here is an example from the [official documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html):

```yaml
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

// NuGet packages
nuget NUnit ~> 2.6.3
nuget FAKE ~> 3.4
nuget DotNetZip >= 1.9
```

From the source code, here is a [test](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/e65f8a5760fb9f7014f48d309bf537ff540bf749/tests/Paket.Tests/Packaging/TemplateFileParsing.fs#L959) and the [parser](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/e65f8a5760fb9f7014f48d309bf537ff540bf749/src/Paket.Core/PaketConfigFiles/TemplateFile.fs#L38) (which uses the regex `^\s*(#|(\/\/))`)